# What happens when a bounty question has no good answer.?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I asked a question on SO, and there was only one answer given to that. I could not understand that and hence I decided to give it a bounty. Now its 4 days since bounty and I have not received any new answers. The old answer is nether accepted nor having votes. And I don't want to award bounty to that. Now how and who will get the bounty if no new answers come after the bounty ends.?

[Here is the link to the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228900/how-to-update-the-pnr-capcha-added-in-the-indian-railways-site)